# How to disable a specific analysis option rule in a folder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I have a project which can be simplified to:

```
lib/
 |- main.dart
test/
test_environment/
 |- test_test.dart
```

Where `test_environment` contains a set of *"special"* tests that cannot simply be run with

```
flutter test
```

They need some specific setting (for example: `flutter test --dart-define=myVar=myValue`).

---

In my `lib/main.dart`, I have something like:

```dart
class MyClass {
  @visibleForTesting
  MyClass.testConstructor();
}
```

I would like to use `MyClass.testConstructor()` from `test/test_helper.dart`. But when I do, I have a warning:

```
The member 'MyClass.testConstructor' can only be used within 'package:my_project/lib/main.dart' or a test. dart(invalid_use_of_visible_for_testing_member)`
```

I would like to disable this rule for the `test_environment/` folder, but not for the `lib/` folder. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution I found was to create a custom `analysis_options.yaml` for the folder `test_environment/` that extends the root `analysis_options.yaml`:

```
lib/
 |- main.dart
test/
test_environment/
 |- test_test.dart
 |- analysis_options.yaml
analysis_options.yaml
```

And in `test_environment/analysis_options.yaml`:

```yaml
include: ../analysis_options.yaml

analyzer:
  errors:
    invalid_use_of_visible_for_testing_member: ignore # <- Disable the analyzer rule.

linter:
  rules:
    only_throw_errors: false # <- An example to show how to disable a linter rule.
```

This takes the analyzer/linter rules set by the root `analysis_options.yaml` and overrides the `invalid_use_of_visible_for_testing_member` to disable it in `test_environment`.